# jQueryUI sortable (as a grid) shifts row beneath itself when float applied directly to element

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-float, jquery-ui-sortable

This problem is easier seen than described. See here: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLW9m/8/)**

To get a clearer understanding of what is going on, I have updated the fiddle to include a class `.ui-sortable-placeholder` to be visible and red. This is the class of the jQueryUI (normally) invisible element involved with the sortable. As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/rLW9m/9/. Thanks to George for pointing that out in his answer. With this answer we can probably consider this resolved as far as the "what" but perhaps the "why" is still TBD.

Of the three scenarios shown, they all apply `float:left` to the LI elements but the final one behaves poorly; in the last bunch of sorted items, clicking on the first or second item "drops" the rest of the list **beneath** the row they were just in (and the item clicked).

The scenario is exhibited when the `float:left` CSS is applied directly to my `<li>`s using inline styling versus applying the same change via a css file. Is this a jQueryUI bug?

When I apply the CSS to my elements in the identical way to how [jQueryUI's documentation](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid) shows (the first example in the jsFiddle), then the sorting occurs just fine. However, once the same CSS (as far as I understand it) is applied *directly* to my list items, then sorting behavior is erratic as described above.

The way to get jQueryUI to sort nicely in a grid is to apply the float *only* in your CSS file using classes or other mechanisms:

```
/* Starting from UL descriptor with LI descendants */
.ulClass li {
    float:left;
}
/* or directly to LI element but still via CSS file */
.makeTheseLIsSortable {
    float:left;
}
/* DOES NOT WORK properly to directly apply CSS 
   (items to the right are shifted below when items on left selected) */
<ul id='makeSortable'>
    <li style='float:left'>test</li>
    <li style='float:left'>three</li>
</ul>
```

Why are these two CSS applications handled so differently by jQueryUI? When it is rendered, it sure seems like the list elements themselves are `float:left` either way. What is your take? Why can't I apply the CSS directly to the list elements and get the same, expected behavior?

**EDIT**: Thanks to George, I now have a better understanding of what is going on. There are probably some really good reasons that jQueryUI *doesn't* copy down the element inline styles to their "placeholder element" but they do pass along class details. If a jQueryUI pro shows up later and considers this a bug then I'm glad to have reported it. Until then, be sure to apply your sortable element's float via a `class`! Can you explain why the inline styling is not included into the placeholder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the place holder that jqueryUI inserts does not have a float left style on it. jQueryUI duplicates the element type and the classes on an item you are sorting for the place holder but it would appear it does not duplicate the inline styles.

Comment: Excellent exploration into this conundrum; I will recognize this as the answer and I updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/rLW9m/9/) to make it a little more obvious what is going on behind-the-scenes. Thanks for your inspiration.